# Transitive verb meaning "to author a strong and direct refutation of or response to"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, transitive-verbs

Wiktionary defines *polemic* as:

> ​A strong verbal or written attack on someone or something.

I need a verb that means "to write a polemic of".

Anyone knows one?

Comment: Isn't a polemic an attack and not a response?

Comment: Does *[polemicize](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/polemicize#Verb)* differ from what you want?

Comment: An example sentence or three with a `_____` left in place of the verb desideratum would be useful.

Comment: @jwpat7 yes, because it's intransitive.

Answer (score 1):

There’s some question about whether you mean to attack or to defend. The OED defines ***polemic*** as:

> A controversial argument or discussion; argumentation against some opinion, doctrine, etc.; aggressive controversy; in *pl.* the practice of this, esp. as a method of conducting theological controversy: opposed to *irenics.*

Given that and combined with your clarifying comment below, you might do well to consider either of ***refute*** or ***repudiate***.

---

There’s also *denounce*, *inveigh (against)*, or even *harangue*.

Straying only slightly from the main thrust, there are also verbs like *decry*, *rebuke*, *vilify*, and *excoriate*.

Venturing still further away leads to the territory of *impugn*, *vituperate*, *reproach*, or *dress (down)*.

And yes, not all of these are strictly transitive, and certainly not all are bitransitive without the aid of a preposition. You might supply an example sentence to make this easier on us.

Comment: I was thinking in the context of writing.  For instance, in writing "the incoherence of the incoherence," averroes _____ed the essay "the incoherence of the philosophers."  I don't believe that polemicize works here.

Comment: @user54974 I agree that *polemicize* doesn’t work there. I myself would likely use *refuted* in that scenario. By the way, very nice reference to [Averroës](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Averroes), one of the “three great philosophers of Córdoba” — the other two being of course Seneca and Maimonides. See also [*People From Córdoba, Spain: Maimonides, Seneca the Younger, Averroes, Lucan, Abd-Ar-Rahman Iii, Luis de Góngora, Martyrs of Córdoba, Ibn Hazm* (ISBN 978-1-159-24473-6)](http://www.gettextbooks.com/isbn/9781159244736).

Comment: The problem is that refute only has the connotations of entailing lengthy written responses in the its usage context.  ideally i want something that has that meaning by itself, sort of like polemic does, except that it is a noun.